# Make Item go the bottom using Flexbox and Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I am trying to add Unassigned Text to the bottom of my Container, as shown in this mockup:[image]

Below is the code, that I have so far. I am struggling to get the border between the play button working too. I have tried the usual css: `bottom:0` and `position:relevant` Along with Flexbox but it doesn't seem to want to go to the very bottom of the container.

```
 const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 3),
  },
  paper: {
    maxWidth: 800,
    margin: `${theme.spacing(2)}px auto`,
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    width: 200,
  },
  playButton: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    position: "relative",
    "& .playButton": {
      position: "absolute",
      top: "60%",
      left: "-55px",
      transform: "translateY(-50%)",
    },
      "& .star-rating": {
        "& .fa-star": {
          "&:hover": {
            "&::before": {
              content: "\f005",
              color: "yellow"
            }
          }
        }
      },
    },
});

function Tasks(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm container>
            <Grid item xs container direction="column" spacing={2}>
              <Grid item xs>
              <div className="name-label">
              Name
              </div>
              <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
              {props.name}
              </Typography>
              <div className="form-divider"></div>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                {props.description}
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item classes={{ root: props.classes.playButton}}>
    <Grid item xs={3} className="playButton">
      <i class="far fa-play-circle fa-2x"></i>
    </Grid>
    <div className="workers-assigned-label">
      Workers Assigned
    </div>
    <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
        0/25
      </Typography>
      <div class="star-rating">
        <label class="far fa-star fa-2x"></label>
        <label class="far fa-star fa-2x"></label>
        <label class="far fa-star fa-2x"></label>
      </div>
    <div className="dropdown-menu">
  <h5>Unnassigned</h5>
</div>
  </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Tasks);
```

Any input would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend starting with a Grid 'skeleton' that looks something like:

```
<Grid container>
  <Grid item container xs={8} direction="column" justify="flex-start">
    // Left column contents, with each row as a <Grid item>
  </Grid>
  <Fab className={classes.fab}><PlayIcon /><Fab>
  <Grid item container xs={4} direction="column" justify="space-between" className={classes.right}>
    // Right column contents, with each row as a <Grid item>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The `direction=column` will help you position items vertically within each container.  The `justify=space-between` will ensure that your first item is at the top of the container and your last item (the unassigned text) is at the bottom.

The "right" css class looks like:

```
right: {
  borderLeft: `1px solid ${theme.palette.grey[500]}`,
  position: "relative"
}
```

You can give it a position of "relative" to make it easier to position the fab relative to the column.  The "fab" class looks like:

```
fab: {
  position: "absolute",
  margin: "auto",
  top: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  left: -28
}
```

The margin, top, and bottom properties help center the fab vertically, and the left is a bit of a hack based on the dimensions of the fab to center it over the border.

Here's a working draft that brings everything together: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-torvalds-dlbke?fontsize=14

Comment: That looks great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, or give `flex: 1` to anything in the column to make it stretch.

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  playButton: {
    '& .dropdown-menu': {
      marginTop: "auto"
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I have tried that and it doesn't quite sit at the very bottom, I think in Material UI the Paper component has padding on it by default, I have tried to override it, but then it messes with the layout.